# Convert Jupiter Tessellation(JT) files to JSON to render in THREE.js

Tags: json, three.js, webgl

How do I render .JT files in THREE.js? I checked following options and could not get anything to proceed with:

1. checked in Three.js on different loaders which are available - didn't get loader for JT files. Please let me know if there is anything already present which I am missing in three.js.
2. http://www.johannes-raida.de/jnetcad.htm - if I have to write my own conversion method, at this of point, not sure how to proceed with. any pointer will be helpful

Any help or pointers will be appriciated.

Thanks in advance,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

JNetCAD won't help you a huge amount unless you write it as a web service. Its Java (server side code) while three.js is client side. If you wanted to go down this route though, you could create a small RESTful web service that took a .JT file as input and returned the converted JSON. This does require a fair amount of Java knowledge though.

Unless you specifically need on-the-fly transformation, you're probably going to find it a lot easier to just run the .JT file through the tool yourself and work directly from a supported format. This is what they have done on the JNetCAD web page to good effect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Recently came to know about jCADLib (https://code.google.com/p/jcadlib/). Do you think this will help? right now,I am just trying to set up... will post once if I make any progress on this

Comment: You'll be facing the same problem. Java (jCADLib) and JavaScript (Three.js) are not the same thing. Java runs on a server, while JavaScript is downloaded by the viewer and runs in the browser. It will help you convert your .JT file into something that is natively supported by Three.js (e.g. Obj or JSON) but so would JNetCAD. It's not going to let you use .JT files natively with Three.js

Comment: @Pradeep is there any progress on this ?? i'm stuck at where u were when u asked the question..